# Why I can't import pdfplumber

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

When I was trying to import pdfplumber, it gives me error.

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

### In [1]: import pdfplumber

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import pdfplumber

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfplumber/**init**.py in ()
---->

```
1 from pdfplumber.pdf import PDF
      2 import pdfplumber.utils
      3 import pdfminer
      4 import pdfminer.pdftypes
      5 from ._version import __version__
```

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfplumber/pdf.py in ()
      4

```
    5 from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
----> 6 from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
      7 from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
      8 from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager,
```

PDFPageInterpreter

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py in ()

```
    24 from .pdftypes import PDFTypeError
     25 from .pdftypes import PDFStream
---> 26 from .pdftypes import PDFObjectNotFound
     27 from .pdftypes import decipher_all
     28 from .pdftypes import int_value
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFObjectNotFound'

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried installing pdfminer as well,if you lack it that might be the cause because from the middle part it seems like a dependent

Answer (score -3):

You should install `imagemagick` as guided here

Restart after installed and then, import `pdfplumber` again